# How to convert the below sql group by statement to Linq

Tags: linq, t-sql

I am new to LINQ and was trying to convert the below TSQL to LINQ, Is there any way i can do this? Thanks for all the help.

This is SQL Statement I am trying to convert

```
SELECT [t5].[StatusID], [t5].[FriendlyName], sum(1) AS [Count]  
FROM (  
SELECT distinct [t0].DealID, [t0].[StatusID], [t1].[FriendlyName]  
FROM [DR_Deal] AS [t0]  
INNER JOIN [DR_DealStage] AS [t1] ON [t0].[StatusID] = [t1].[DealStageID]  
INNER JOIN [DR_Deal_ApproverInfo] AS [t2] ON [t0].[DealID] = [t2].[DealID]  
INNER JOIN [DR_Approver] AS [t3] ON [t2].[ApproverID] = ([t3].[ApproverID])  
INNER JOIN [DR_Profile] AS [t4] ON [t3].[ProfileID] = ([t4].[ProfileID])  
WHERE (LOWER([t4].[Email]) = @p0) OR (LOWER([t0].[CreatedBy]) = @p1)  
) AS [t5]  
GROUP BY [StatusID], [FriendlyName]  
ORDER BY [t5].[StatusID]
```

```
EDITS
```

**yes the above sql is generated using linqpad, this is what i really want to convert to linq**

    `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [t0].DealID) AS count, [t0].[StatusID], [t1].[FriendlyName]

    FROM [DR_Deal] AS [t0]

    INNER JOIN [DR_DealStage] AS [t1] ON [t0].[StatusID] = [t1].[DealStageID]

    INNER JOIN [DR_Deal_ApproverInfo] AS [t2] ON [t0].[DealID] = [t2].[DealID]

    INNER JOIN [DR_Approver] AS [t3] ON [t2].[ApproverID] = ([t3].[ApproverID])

    INNER JOIN [DR_Profile] AS [t4] ON [t3].[ProfileID] = ([t4].[ProfileID])

    WHERE (LOWER([t4].[Email]) = LOWER(@Email)) OR (LOWER([t0].[CreatedBy]) = LOWER(@UserName))

    GROUP BY [t0].[StatusID], [t1].[FriendlyName]

    ORDER BY [t0].[StatusID]`

And I think I found the solution to do the `count(distinct)` using linq which I initially stumbled upon, but still the converted solution didn't work, I am thinking the below linq code is not working because i am using **sql 2000** and the generated sql have nested selects and there seems some limitation with sql 2000. I am still not sure about my conclusions, may be the linq blelow is wrong altogther or there might be a better way to write the above sql.

```
var query = (from d in DR_Deal  
join s in DR_DealStage  
on d.StatusID equals s.DealStageID  
join da in DR_Deal_ApproverInfo  
on d.DealID equals da.DealID  
join a in DR_Approver  
on da.ApproverID equals a.ApproverID  
join p in DR_Profile  
on a.ProfileID equals p.ProfileID  
where p.Email.ToLower().Equals("test@test.com")   
|| d.CreatedBy.ToLower().Equals("test")  
group d.DealID by new { d.StatusID, s.FriendlyName}  
into grp  
select new  
{  
  StatusID = grp.Key.StatusID,  
  FriendlyName = grp.Key.FriendlyName,  
  Count = grp.Distinct().Count()  
}).OrderBy(x=> x.StatusID);
```

Comment: for me the t-sql you have submitted seems linq-to-sql provider generated sql. What's the exact problem you've bumped into.

Comment: A useful tool I found for learning LINQ is **LinqPAD** You can find it here [www.linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: @nasmifive: I agree, that looks very much like the T-Sql generated by Linq-to-Sql

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of ways to do this but I did some thing similar and mapped it to an object. This statement isn't totally right for your problem but you can use the below to mix distinct values with agregate (having, group, count, sum) values etc.

```
             IEnumerable<MyObject> myObj                  
              =  (from d in dbContext.DR_Deal          
             /*DO ALL YOUR JOINS */ 
             join ds in dbContext.DR_DealStage on d.statusID equals ds.dealstageID
             where ds.mycolumn == myvalue

             select new MyObject()
             {
                   groupedByObject = d,
                   singleColumnsValue = ds.columnName
                   /* For calculated values have inner LINQ statements which join
                   back to elements from the main query. These can also 
                   return objects*/
                   agregateValue = (from x in dbContext.OtherTable
                                    where x.id == d.id).Count()
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ALWAYS fall back on 101 LinQ samples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746